# How does Ruby evaluate double quotes (aka "") vs. String.new?

Tags: ruby

What's the difference in how Ruby initializes a new string with double quotes (`""`) vs. `String.new`?  For curiosity and experimentation purposes, I overrode `String#initialize`:

```
class String
  def initialize
    puts "I <3 bananas" # they're delicious!
  end
end
```

What I'm trying to figure out is: why are these two examples different?

```
# Calling the String class directly, I can declare banana love!
irb(main):054:0> String.new
I <3 bananas
=> ""

# Using double quotes, this string is not as tasty :(
irb(main):055:0> ""
=> ""
```

This is annoying to research because every Google result seems to be focused on basic Ruby syntax, and I haven't been able to find anything in the Ruby documentation.

Comment: What happens if you override `allocate` instead?

Comment: @RyanBigg That's a good thought, but it doesn't make a difference.  String literals are evaluated and have their object created at compile time, bypassing both `initialize` and `allocate`.

Comment: @DarshanComputing, thanks!  It sounds like I'd have to hack and recompile Ruby from source to make "" return the initialize stuff.  I'll read up more on literals.

Answer (score 10):

According to [Matz](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1893190#1004250):

> String objects
>   for literals are already created in the compile time, which is far
>   before you redefine the initialize method.  The individual string
>   objects from literals are just copy of the already allocated and
>   initialized objects.  The whole purpose of the initialize method is to
>   initialize newly created objects, as the name suggests.  I don't feel
>   any need to call the (redefined) initialize method for string
>   literals, that already initialized at the compile time.

Comment: Of course, that's how it works in pretty much every other programming language as well. The only two examples I know of which allow overloading of literals are Ioke and Seph.